# how to export flash to Animated SVG

Tags: flash

I’ve tried it before but been unsuccessful at getting it to work. Regardless I’d like to try again and was wondering before plunging in whether you’ve tested and/or support the new Flash CC 2015 update?

Answer (score 0):

you could try TomBryne's [Flash2Svg](https://github.com/TomByrne/Flash2Svg), I know it worked up to CC2014 but haven't tried it with 2015 yet.

Nipun Asthana also created an exported which I believe works with CC2015, you can download here and see some [documentation here](https://nipunasthana.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/export-svg-sequence/)

Comment: @BhavikPatel did either solution work for you or did you find a better method in the end?